# Maven transitive dependency warning - can't find parent dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Maven keeps giving me a WARNING regarding a transitive dependency which I don't know where its coming from!

When I run mvn clean install, I get this:

```
[WARNING] The POM for commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
```

When I issued mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ MyApp ---
[INFO] com.example:MyApp:war:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-feed:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.rome:rome-fetcher:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.java.dev.rome:rome:jar:1.0.0:compile
```

This tells me that is dependent and being pulled in because of spring-core dependency...

However when try to exclude it, by using the

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Inside the spring-core dependency, the WARNING for commons-logging-1.1.3 KEEPS appearing and is also located inside 
WEB-INF/lib, tried to exclude it using:

```
<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar</packagingExcludes>
```

Here's my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org-springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org-springframework-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Framework -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org-springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- other dependencies omitted to make code snippet short -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run mvn dependency:tree the WARNING still occurs but doesn't appear anywhere in stdout! How can I turn this annoying WARNING off and not let it bring in this jar into my WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: I took your above pom with copy/paste and ran `mvn clean package` (well, after I removed the dependency `org.apache.commons/commons-logging` which apparently does not exist in Maven Central). I also tried with `dependency:tree`
I get no such warning as you do. Using Maven 3.5.0 / Java 8.

Comment: You need to change it to `commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3` which exists in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccommons-logging%7Ccommons-logging%7C1.1.3%7Cjar)